# Make changes in XML file with javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, safari-extension

I'm making a safari extension and i need to make a change in the info.plist file from javascript.

My javascript file is at /scripts

So when a setting with a checkbox is changed the javascript puts the true/false value of that setting into the info.plist

How do i change a plist file (xml formatted) with javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather not be the bearer of bad news, but it's not possible for a Safari extension to programmatically change its own (much less any other) info.plist file. At least, there is no documented API method for doing so.

If you want to store a setting, using the safari.extension.settings object (or .secureSettings object) is the conventional way to do it—but that's probably not what you had in mind.